# Redirect URL (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net

Suppose, one is requesting for the following url:
`http://mysite.com/`

I want to redirect it to:
`http://mysite.com/myfolder`

Is it any configuration in `web.config` file? Or, how can I do it? Please help.

Comment: You've asked quite a few questions, and judging by the look of things, you've gotten several pretty good answers. For those answers that have worked for you, please mark as a "best answer" or at least upvote those that been at all helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 301 redirects.check the following links.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Redirect301ASP_NET.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true